# Kendo Grid not binding to data in asp.net mvc core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, kendo-grid

The grid definition in asp.net mvc core chtml

```
 <div class="text-center">


  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<COSalesDto>()
                    .Name("grid")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(p => p.CatalogNumber);
                        columns.Bound(p => p.UsageCode).Width(150);
                    })
                    .Pageable()
                    .Sortable()
                    .Filterable()
                    .Events(events => events
                        .DataBound("onDataBound")
                        .DataBinding("onDataBinding"))
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .PageSize(20)
                        .Read(read => read.Action("ChangeOrder_Read", "Naco"))
                    ).Deferred()
                )

</div>
```

Here is my data returned from ajax call

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "CatalogNumber": "Catalog 12345",
      "UsageCode": "Usage Code 1"
    },
    {
      "CatalogNumber": "Catalog 8234758",
      "UsageCode": "Usage Code 2"

    }

  ],
  "Total": 0,
  "AggregateResults": null,
  "Errors": null
}
```

all events are triggering on grid, but no databinding happending.

This is on asp.net core mvc 3.1
here is my entry in startup

```
 services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new AbpAutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
            })    
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            })
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks
V

Comment: It seems that there is a charge for kendo-grid，I can't reproduce the issue .I suggest you could ask the question on [Telerik Forums](https://www.telerik.com/forums/aspnet-core-ui/grid) for more help.

Comment: Thank you, I am also trying with Telerik, no luck yet. The challenge is combination of AspNetZero and Telerik

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with NewtonsoftJson and Kendogrid binding. If we remove services.AddMvcWithControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(); The bindings works, but abp cod will have challenges.

Thanks
v

Answer (score 0):

I confirm what https://stackoverflow.com/users/3054585/user3054585
I've just removed the AddNewtonsoftJson from my service registration, and everything is working fine now.

That's strange, my version is ASP.NET CORE 6.0